# Casual, stylish jacket for cycling?

Tags: commuter, accessories, rain, wind, jacket

I've been looking for a commuting jacket for a few months and haven't found anything suitable.

Are there any **casual-looking jackets** with the following features for autumn/winter commuting in a city like London?

Mandatory requirements:

- Does not look like a cycling or sports jacket, but completely casual
- Windproof
- Water-resistant (at least) shell
- Zip-up (or buttons) up to the neck
- Adjustable at the waist (so that wind doesn't come in)
- Venting/holes at the armpits and/or other strategic locations

Optional:

- Some reflectors on the back (don't have to be big)
- Waterproof hood with adjusters to make it tight around the head so you can look back while cycling (e.g. like on the Patagonia Torrentshell jacket)

I've tried the following jackets and found them unsuitable:

[image: Levi's jacket]

- **Levi's Commuter Trucker Jacket:** this seemed like a perfect balance of the above requirements, but was extremely loose around the waist — with no option to tighten. On a size down, it was so tight around my chest that the buttons would pop open when moving my arms. Has potential, but not designed with enough function in mind.

[image: Vulpine jacket]

- **Vulpine Harrington Rain Jacket:** this also seemed great but was not tight enough around the waist to prevent cold air from coming in (in several sizes). The special cut-out cuffs were more of an inconvenience when walking (too long, covering my hands) than a benefit. The pocket on the back is also too visible, taking away from the casual look. This jacket also had potential, but needs changes.

Comment: Most outdoor(technical) brands have urban wear now.  Not cheap but check http://arcteryx.com/product.aspx?language=EN&gender=mens&collection=New_for_Fall_2015&model=Interstate-Jacket.  Patagonia also has urban styles.

Comment: I agree with @Frisbee, I have a walking jacket bought from an outdoor store which basically fits those requirements. But something to watch out for - I think I'd find my jacket a bit restrictive if I tried cycling in it, it is probably too waterproof and not breathable enough.

Comment: -1 "Must look completely casual"

Comment: Try an op-shop and see what they have.  Cheaper than buying new ones and not liking them.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try BetaBrand. They are costly but these are the only cloths that I've found that meet that criteria. THey have a whole line of "bike to work" clothes

https://www.betabrand.com/collections/bike-to-work.html